Computed is still dirty after getter evaluation, with dependency being set asyncronously
I have a pinia store which loads data on demand from a database (specifically Firestore, but I don't think it matters).
When the data is queried, it sets a value into a reactive Map ({ id: <id>, loaded: false }).
When the database query returns (via a promise) it sets the same map value to the data loaded from the database.
At the same time, a computed ref is returned to the initial call site, returning a db value if the data is present (loaded == true), or the id if not.
This works, but I have been getting the Computed is still dirty after getter evaluation, likely because a computed is mutating its own dependency in its getter warning, presumably because the promise is resolving while the computed property is calculating.
Is there any way to suppress this warning, as I want the computed property to recalculate when the data changes, and it will happen a maximum of once for each entry in the database that is queried.
The code for my store is below (typescript)
export const usePlayerStore = defineStore("player", () => {
  const db = getFirestore();

  const loadedPlayers = ref(new Map<string, LoadedPlayer>());
  const subscriptions = new Map<string, Unsubscribe>();
  const loadPlayer = (playerId: string) => {
    if (!subscriptions.has(playerId)) {
      subscriptions.set(
        playerId,
        onSnapshot(doc(db, "players", playerId), (snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists()) {
            const p = new LoadedPlayer(playerId, snapshot.data() as DBPlayer);
            // Warning caused by this line
            loadedPlayers.value.set(playerId, p);
          } else {
            loadedPlayers.value.delete(playerId);
          }
        }),
      );
    }
  };
  const playerName = (playerId: string) => {
    loadPlayer(playerId);
    // Warning caused by this computed property
    return computed(() => {
      const p = loadedPlayers.value.get(playerId);
      if (p) {
        return p.name;
      }
      return playerId;
    });
  };
  const getPlayer = (playerId: string): Ref<Player> => {
    loadPlayer(playerId);
    return computed(
      () =>
        (loadedPlayers.value.get(playerId) as LoadedPlayer | undefined) ?? {
          id: playerId,
          loaded: false,
          name: playerId,
        },
    );
  };

  return {
    loadPlayer,
    playerName,
    getPlayer,
  };
});

Sample use (a table with a column for each player):
Written using Vue JSX
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    players: { type: Array as PropType<string[]>, required: true },
  },
  setup: (props) => {
    const playerStore = usePlayerStore();
    return () => <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          {props.players.map(pid => <td class="playerName" data-player-id={pid}>{playerStore.playerName(pid).value}</td>)}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {/* Dynamic table body content here */}
      </tbody>
    </table>;
  }
})


Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve instead of describing it. Since the problem is caused by specific code, it needs to be addressed specifically

Hard to help without actual code. Also please Google that error, might not be the first one with the specific issue.

@EstusFlask I didn't post the code, as it was more a question about a general solution to the reported race condition (the change occurring during the computed calculation) than specifically about this issue.

@kissu That was my first approach, but all I could find was for use in synchronous code.

@Alpvax I see. It's very specific to your case. The warning isn't something common, and the actual problem is that computeds are misused. Is playerName an action? An action shouldn't return a new ref/computed. Most times actions don't return any result at all. I posted an answer, it still depends on the intended use of the store how it needs to be rewritten, this is not shown yet

The computeds are misused, they are supposed to be defined once on store initialization, they shouldn't be called multiple times with return computed.
A parametrized computed could be defined like:
const getPlayerName = computed(() => (playerId: string) => {...});

But a computed needs to be separated from side effects like loadPlayer:
loadPlayer('foo');

watchEffect(() => {
  const fooName  = getPlayerName.value('foo'),
  ...
);

It also would make sense for loadPlayer to return a promise for strict control flow, this would allow the action to return a promise of a result and avoid possible race conditions resulting from a player not being loaded at the time when it's accessed.

Thanks. I wanted getPlayerName to return a computed property of either the player name or the pid, depending on whether the player was loaded (there is no name available when not loaded). That way I can use the property in components to display the name and it will automatically update when the database query returns, without having to define the computed property in each component (they are used as lists of players, so lists of computed properties). Could you advise a better approach to do this if this is the wrong approach?

loadPlayer doesn't need to return a promise, as I don't actually care whether a player is loaded yet, I just want to initiate it if it isn't already loading.

I'd expect it to be done like suggested in the answer. Separate loadPlayer from a computed, with getPlayerName being reactive. Is there a case where this approach causes problems?

So if I have a component with a (reactive) list of player IDs, and I want to display them as names when available, I should have the entire getName function being reactive, not a ComputedRef[]? How would I ensure that the players are being loaded? Should I have a separate watcher on the list and call store.loadPlayer for each?

My goal was to have the whole thing work as a composable where I could just expose a single method to the call site for getting the player name and loading in the background. Should that be separated into a separate composable with a watcher inside it which itself refers to the store?

Can you provide a simplified comp that consumes this data and reflects your real usage, so it could be specifically addressed? The way this should work depends on what happens with getPlayerName. Generally you'd have {{ getPlayerName('foo') }} in the template and loadPlayer('foo') in script part (probably inside a watcher if 'foo' is dynamic value), and this would work. I'm quite sure there's more than one way to achieve this in general, but as for pinia part of it, it's supposed to be rather strict, there are "getters" and "actions"

I have added a sample simplified component to the OP. The players prop may not come from the database, so there is no guarantee that the players with the given ids are loaded. It would be nice to be able to query the names with a simple function, but I'm not 100% sure how the reactivity would work if it was just a function rather than returning a computed ref. Am I massively overcomplicating things?

I'd expect it to be watchEffect(() => { props.players.forEach(pid => store.loadPlayer(pid)) }) in comp setup and {store.getPlayerName(pid)} in render function. The reactivity is enabled by the fact that loadedPlayers.value.get() is accessed inside getPlayerName when render function runs. A computed won't improve reactivity on its own, it's useful for optimization, though not in this case.  getPlayerName actually could be regular function that returns a string, it doesn't benefit a lot from being computed(), this is just a convention and prevents it from being reassigned in the store
